# Usage of "bereits", "gerade", "schon" and "gleich"

Tags: particle

I'm acquainted with many meanings and uses of *bereits*, *gerade*, *schon* and *gleich*; but sometimes some of these words are equivalents and sometimes not; and sometimes, too, they may entertain more than one meaning.
For instance:

> Als ich zur Party kam, waren die meisten Gäste bereits heimgegangen.

Does this mean: "... most of the guests had already left" or "... most of the guests had just left"? And, in German, which would be a more exact synonymous: "... waren die meisten Gäste schon heimgegangen"? or "waren die meisten Gäste gerade heimgegangen" or "... gleich heimgegangen"?

It seems to me that, in the case of Perfekt and Plusquamperfekt, *gerade* means the same as *gleich* and *bereits* (already with the addition of just a few seconds/minutes ago), and *schon* means just already.

Is my thought correct?

Comment: Du möchtest, dass wir jetzt 3 Vergleiche mit `bereits` machen, plus 2 mit `gerade` die wir noch nicht hatten, und einen zwischen `schon und gleich`? `Gleich` kann man hier gar nicht sagen. Man kann sagen sie seien gleich nach dem Essen gegangen. `Bereits` und `schon` sind hier untereinander gleich und bedeuten `already` während `gerade` `just` bedeutet, jawohl.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your examples and in almost all cases "*bereits*" and "*schon*" are interchangeable. You can simply replace "*bereits*" with "*schon*", as it means "*already*":

> Als ich zur Party kam, waren die meisten Gäste bereits/schon heimgegangen.
>   When I arrived at the party most of the guests had already left.

There are however a few sayings where "*schon*" can't be replaced with "*bereits*":

> Schon gut.
>   Never mind./All right.

Another one, where you could use "*bereits*" but it's not very common:

> Das war schon immer so gewesen.
>   It had always been like that.

---

Let's take a look at "*gleich*". This doesn't make much sense:

> Als ich zur Party kam, waren die meisten Gäste gleich heimgegangen.

But you could say:

> Als ich zur Party kam, *sind* die meisten Gäste gleich heimgegangen.
>   As soon as I arrived at the party, most of the guests just left.

Which implies that they left because of your arrival.

Here is another example to show the difference:

> Ich bin bereits/schon da.
>   I'm already there.

versus:

> Ich bin gleich da.
>   I'm almost there.

You may say that "*schon/bereits*" describes something that is completed whereas "*gleich*" can have multiple meanings, like *at that moment*, *almost* or even *equality*:

> 4 + 5 ist *gleich* 5 + 4.
>   4 + 5 *equals* 5 + 4.

This is also an addition axiom. — but that's another topic, so nevermind. ;)